# Updating immutable map as the side effect of getOrElse

Tags: scala

Sometimes I use a `Map` as a memoization cache. With mutable maps, I use `getOrElseUpdate`:

```
mutableMap.getOrElseUpdate(key, {
    val value = <compute the value>
    value
})
```

Immutable maps don't have `getOrElseUpdate`. So I want to do this

```
immutableMap.getOrElse(key, {
    val value = <compute the value>
    immutableMap += key -> value
    value
})
```

This seems to work in practice, I have good arguments to believe it works in theory, and it's more or less readable -- is it a terrible idea for some reason I'm missing?

---

The other alternatives I'm considering are

```
immutableMap.get(key) match {
    case Some(value) => value
    case None =>
        val value = <compute the value>
        immutableMap += key -> value
        value
}
```

which is not much different and is more cumbersome, or

```
if (immutableMap.contains(key)) {
    immutableMap(key)
} else {
    val value = <compute the value>
    immutableMap += key -> value
    value
}
```

which is the dumbest and probably least idiomatic.

In principle I rather *not* go for a solution that uses a helper to return the value and the updated map, unless it's the unarguably superior way.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, it seems reasonable except for one small issue... it's not updating your collection! If you're using an immutable Map, then that Map is immutable. You can not change it, ever.

In fact, immutable Map from Scala collection does not even have a `+=` method defined on it, see [immutable.Map](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Map). All the methods with "append" or "add" new values to the Map actually return a *new* Map. So for what you've written above to compile, you'd have to not be using something immutable.

To do this with an immutable map, you'll need to work with a `var` and replace that `var` with the new Map (which can lead to issues with threading) or you have to adopt a State Monad type pattern in which you return not only the new value but also the new Map.

```
def getOrCalc(m: Map[Key, Value], k: Key)(f: Key => Value): (Map[Key, Value], Value] ={
  if(m.contains(k)) (m, m(k))
  else{
    val value = f(k)
    (m +: (k, value), value)
  }
}
```

Comment: _"To do this with an immutable map, you'll need to work with a var and replace that var with the new Map"_ -- sure, that's what I'm doing with `immutableMap += key -> value`

Comment: @ggambett You'd do better with a mutable Map since, in actuality, you really want a mutable Map. Why go to the trouble to hide the mutability when you could be forthright and explicit?

Comment: For thread safety. Since it's a memoization cache, the values are deterministic, so I don't care which thread gets to update the `var` first. On the other hand I've had actual problems with multithreaded access to a mutable map.

Comment: @ggambett The minute you use a `var` without locking, you lose thread safety. You are mutating state! You are going to have the same, exact issues. Just because you use an immutable data structure doesn't mean you can use `var` that are shared across threads.

Comment: Assuming reassigning the `var` itself is atomic, and the values I put in the map are deterministic, what kind of problems could I have? Or is reassigning the `var` not atomic?

Comment: @ggambett bingo! Reassining the `var` is not atomic.

Comment: Am I reading the JVM memory model wrong? Looks like reference assignments _are_ atomic. _"Writes to and reads of references are always atomic, regardless of whether they are implemented as 32-bit or 64-bit values."_ from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.7

Comment: @ggambet your `getOrElse` acts in non-atomic way, however it may not be a problem for you if you don't care about several redundant calculations (assuming they're all do same calculation). Assigning the `var` is atomic, so it won't corrupt your collection if you don't care about `getOrElse`.

Comment: @dk14 Right, that makes sense. I don't care about that, it's what I meant by _"Since it's a memoization cache, the values are deterministic, so I don't care which thread gets to update the `var` first."_

Answer (score 0):

My only recommendation (regarding the reasons why you choosed `var` instead of `mutable.Map` or Java's `ConcurrentMap`) is to wrap it into DSL, like:

```
case class Mutable[K,V](var m: Map[K,V]) {
   def orElseUpdate(key: K, compute: => V) = m.getOrElse(key, {
     val value = compute
     m += key -> value
     value
   })
}

scala> val a = Mutable(Map(1 -> 2))
a: Mutable[Int,Int] = Mutable(Map(1 -> 2))

scala> a.orElseUpdate(2, 4)
res10: Int = 4

scala> a.orElseUpdate(2, 6)
res11: Int = 4

scala> a.orElseUpdate(3, 6)
res12: Int = 6
```

Another option (if your computation is lightweight) is just:

```
m += key -> m.getOrElse(key, compute)
m(key)
```

Example:

```
 scala> var m = Map(1 -> 2)
 m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 2)

 scala> m += 3 -> m.getOrElse(3, 5)

 scala> m
 res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 2, 3 -> 5)

 scala> m += 3 -> m.getOrElse(3, 5)

 scala> m
 res3: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 2, 3 -> 5)

 scala> m += 3 -> m.getOrElse(3, 6)

 scala> m
 res5: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 2, 3 -> 5)
```

You can wrap it into DSL as well:

```
implicit class RichMap[K,V](m: Map[K,V]) {
  def kvOrElse(k: K, v: V) = k -> m.getOrElse(k, v)
}

scala> m += m.kvOrElse(3, 7)

scala> m
res7: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 2, 3 -> 5)

scala> m += m.kvOrElse(4, 7)

scala> m
res9: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 2, 3 -> 5, 4 -> 7)
```